# Adding validation to a MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form in a MVC view which has 3 fields, all of which are required.

Here is the model for that form.

```
public class ConfigModel
{
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Email Address")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Security Token")]
    public string SecurityToken { get; set; }
}
```

And in my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Configure", "Home"))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AccountEventID)
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EmailAddress)
}
```

However when I submit that form it goes straight to my controller and the validation message is not displayed. I thought it automatically displays on the client side?

Comment: how does your view code looks like ? Is it using the validation helper methods ?

Comment: Have you included the relevant scripts (`jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`)?

Comment: I posted the relevant part from my view, or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't see a submit button in your form. How are you submitting it ? via javascript ?

Comment: @StephenMuecke cheers lad, never knew I needed those